# an algorithm that is Theta(n) is also O(n^2), is this correct?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

As Theta(n) is about the upper and lower bound, this question confused me.
I am sure O(n) can be O(n^2), but Omega(n) is also O(n^2)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that O(f),Theta(f), Omega(f) are sets of functions.

O(n) is the set of functions that asymptotically grow at most as fast as n (modulo a constant factor), so O(n) is a proper subset of O(n^2).

Omega(n) is the set of functions that asymptotically grow at least as fast as n, so it is definitely not a subset of O(n^2). But it has a non-empty intersection with it, for example 0.5n and 7n^2 are in both sets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically, I felt that question from a quiz weird was weird as Theta is about upper and lower bound. How can it say Theta is O?. But the given answer is right.

Comment: @Fred Great! In that case you should mark the answer as correct so others can see that the question has been answered.